# systemctl start trafficserver wait for start

Tags: systemd, systemctl, apache-traffic-server

I have a script that installs and sets up [traffic server](http://trafficserver.apache.org/):

```
yum install -y trafficserver
systemctl start trafficserver

traffic_line -s proxy.config.url_remap.remap_required -v 0
traffic_line -s proxy.config.reverse_proxy.enabled -v 0
```

The problem is, `traffic_line` fails with:

> [connect] ERROR (main_socket_fd 3): No such file or directory
>   error: could not connect to management port, make sure traffic_manager is running

This is because `systemctl start` returns immediately, without waiting for traffic server to be actually started.

**Is there a way to tell `systemctl start` to only return once the service is started?**

If this is not possible, is there a command that I can run after `systemctl start` to actually wait for the service to be started?

Comment: Why not create a .socket unit that will let systemd hold `traffic_line` until `trafficserver` has finished starting?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Is a .socket unit something that can be run only once? Also, I'm concerned that even when traffic server is considered active by systemd, it's not actually accepting connections from `traffic_line` just yet. Please see my answer below!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> This is because `systemctl start` returns immediately, without waiting for traffic server to be actually started.
>
> **Is there a way to tell `systemctl start` to only return once the service is started?**

`systemctl start` *does* wait for the service to be ready (except if invoked with `--no-block`), the service just needs to indicate that properly (i. e., not use `Type=simple`). If the service doesn’t tell systemd when it’s ready, no variation of `systemctl is-active`, `systemctl show`, etc. will help you.

The most elegant solution, as mentioned in the comments, would be a socket unit. systemd starts the socket, `traffic_line` connects to it, systemd starts the service, and `traffic_line` blocks until the service starts to accept connections on the file descriptor it inherited from systemd.

Alternatively, you can use either `Type=forking` (the service forks, and the main PID exits once the forked service is ready) or `Type=notify` (the service calls `sd_notify(0, "READY=1")` once it’s ready).

Unfortunately, all of these solutions require some support from `trafficserver` – use systemd’s socket instead of allocating its own, fork and wait appropriately in the main process, or call `sd_notify`. systemd can’t magically guess when the server is ready if the server doesn’t cooperate :)

---

After looking at `trafficserver`’s source code a bit, it looks like it might actually support `Type=forking` – the server is spawned by a dedicated `traffic_cop` command, which seems to wait until the server is up and perform some basic testing (at least the code looks like it). So if you change the service type, it might just work:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/trafficserver.service.d/type-forking.conf
[Service]
Type=forking
```

Answer (score 4):

I finally got it to work, after several attempts.

## First attempt

After digging into systemctl help I found the `is-active` command:

```
$ systemctl is-active trafficserver
active
```

I therefore wrote a shell script to wait until the service becomes active:

```sh
while true; do
    if [ $(systemctl is-active trafficserver) == "active" ]; then
        break
    fi

    sleep 1
done
```

Unfortunately, even though this script works as expected when I test it with start/stop, **I was still getting the same error** when running the `traffic_line` commands right after it. I think that the service is reported as active before the actual processes have fully started (probably a matter of milliseconds).

## Second attempt

So I tried another way. Knowing that this is the very first start of the service, I can wait until the PID file of the trafficserver manager exists. Here is what I tried:

```sh
while [ ! -f /run/trafficserver/manager.lock ]; do
  sleep 1
done
```

Same problem: when the trafficserver manager's PID file is written, the manager is not actually ready to receive orders yet, so **I'm still getting the error**.

Damn, *I don't want to use a blind `sleep`*.

## Third attempt

So I ended up checking that the `traffic_line` command itself does not fail:

```sh
while ! traffic_line --status &> /dev/null; do
    sleep 1
done
```

And **this works!**

## Nice, but...

Unfortunately, the answer is very specific to the service I'm using (trafficserver), and would not directly apply to other services.

If you know a more generic answer to this question, please feel free to share it.

Comment: Lucas's answer actually addresses the question asked (how to make `systemctl start` wait for the service), you should accept that instead

Comment: Put that in a helper service or in an ExecPostStart by calling bash https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/324035/8337

Answer (score 2):

I'm bad in shells scripting, but I think that you'd want to test for both, the *ActiveState* and the *SubState* property if the return *active* and *running* respectively.

```
$ systemctl show trafficserver -p SubState,ActiveState
ActiveState=active
SubState=running
```

After that you should be able to run the second portion of your script.

Answer (score -1):

Simplest way would be to add a sleep to the script:

```
sleep 30
```

Or you could do some job control as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356100/how-to-wait-in-bash-for-several-subprocesses-to-finish-and-return-exit-code-0)

Comment: I'd prefer to avoid a sleep-based solution, as it's not 100% safe (although I agree that something really weird would need to happen for the first start to take more than 30s). I checked your link regarding job control, but can't get the PID with `$!` after `systemctl start`.

Comment: I was thinking that you would want `$!` after installation, not after `systemctl start`. Once it's in the realm of `systemctl` it's a lot easier to query the startup process.